# Proving a Matrix using Adjoint Property

Tags: matrices

Let M, N are two non-singular matrix of order 3 with real entries such that $adj(M) = 2N$ and
$adj(N) = M$, then Prove that $MN=2I$

My approach is as follow

$adj\left( M \right) = 2N;adj\left( N \right) = M$

$adj\left( {adj\left( M \right)} \right) = adj\left( {2N} \right) = {\left| M \right|^{3 - 2}}M = 4adj\left( N \right) = 4M$

$\left| M \right| = 4$

$adj\left( {adj\left( N \right)} \right) = adj\left( M \right)$

${\left| N \right|^{3 - 2}}N = 2N \Rightarrow \left| N \right| = 2$

$MN = adj\left( N \right)N$

How do I proceed from here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. $\operatorname{adj}(N)=|N|\cdot N^{-1}$.